# Swift facebook messenger user photos

Tags: swift, swift2

I am trying to create user list like facebook messager chat page.

I can create users and put them in to tableview. Everything working correctly but I dıd not make photo like attach file.

I can create round button but can not give a empty place and put sign in this empty area.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by following below steps
1) Take one UIButton in UITableViewcell.
2) Set Image on it.
3) Programmatically set corner radius and draw white border on UIButton.

Here is the code for step 3

```
self.btnRound.layer.cornerRadius = 15 //btnRound.frame.size.width/2
self.btnRound.clipsToBounds = true
btnRound.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
btnRound.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
```

[image]

Here I have put UIButton on top right corner. Base on requirement you need to put in bottom right corner.

Comment: In your sample green check image and the rocket are 1 image?
If yes this will not work for me because my images will be dynamic

Comment: No both are separate. I have used UIButton for green image. Read my answer from start. I have mentioned steps as well.